# VueJs using simple v-if statement for computeds not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Using simple `v-if` in `Vuejs` i have:

```html
<span v-if="!profile_full_name===''">
    @{{ profile_full_name }}
</span>
<span v-else>
    {{auth()->user()->fullName}}
</span>
```

here `profile_full_name` is a computed method:

```js
profile_full_name() {
    return 
       this.$store.state.profile_name 
           + ' ' + 
       this.$store.state.profile_family
}
```

i want to use `v-if` with `profile_full_name` when it's empty or not empty.
when `profile_full_name` is empty we should be have

```js
@{{ profile_full_name }}
```

end when it's not empty we should see

```php
{{auth()->user()->fullName}}
```

computed and all methods works fine and `@{{ profile_full_name }}` without `v-if` and `v-else` work fine too

```js
export default {
    data() {
        //...
    },
    computed: {
        profile_full_name() {
            return this.$store.state.profile_name + ' ' + this.$store.state.profile_family
        }
    },
    methods: {
        change_name({target}) {
            this.$store.state.profile_name = target.value
        },
        change_family({target}) {
            this.$store.state.profile_family = target.value
        },
    }
};
```

BTW instead of `v-if`, `v-else` works any time

Comment: This `!profile_full_name===''` means _if the opposite of `profile_full_name` equals exactly `""`_ which is weird. Just use `v-if="!profile_full_name"` which means _if `profile_full_name` is "", null, NaN or undefined_

Comment: @Mulhoon unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Looks like the computed profile_full_name may be adding two undefined items with a space in the middle. Try `return this.$store.state.profile_name ? this.$store.state.profile_name + ' ' + this.$store.state.profile_family : null` along with the above

Comment: Like what @Mulhoon said, ensure that either states don't return `undefined`, because concatenating that with a string will result in the string literal `"undefined "`

Comment: @Mulhoon i checked again, it doesn't `undefined` and return what i type in `input` html element and when i don't type into `inputs` value of `profile_full_name` is one space

Comment: do this `v-if="profile_full_name!=''">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your string has a space in it, it will never be equivalent to `''`, so the condition in your `v-if` binding will always return false. Instead, [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) and simply allow the returned string to be evaluated as truthy/falsy:

```
<span v-if="profile_full_name.trim()">
    @{{ profile_full_name }}
</span>
<span v-else>
    {{auth()->user()->fullName}}
</span>
```